# PowerBI – How to set up a streaming data report?

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I have a range of devices that push data to an Azure IoT hub. I then have a stream analytics job which ingests the data from IoThub and outputs it to PowerBI. In PowerBI then I have created a report from the dataset which is working. I now want that report to be ‘live’ using the streaming data from Stream Analytics, but can’t see how to make it so?

Looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-power-bi) guide, under the section ‘*Create and publish a Power BI report to visualize the data*’ point 4 says ‘*Click Streaming Datasets*’ which sounds like exactly what I need, but I don’t see that option anywhere?

Have I missed a step or set something up wrong, or is there another way to make my report ‘live’ without needing manual refresh and publishing?

Here's what I see when creating a report:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the report where you want to add the streaming data tile to.
2. Click on '+ Add tile' over on the top navigation
3. You should see an option for Real time - Custom streaming data on the resulting blade.

Comment: Thanks @Krishna, but I dont see the Add tile option. I've updated the main post with the options I see...

Comment: @LDJ have you managed to solve this dataset issue . Even I cant see Dataset in Power BI.